# Migrating GlassFish to Tomcat throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException

Tags: jsf, tomcat, glassfish

When I changed glassfish server to Apache tomcat then I got this error, how to fix it this error SEVERE: Critical error during deployment I am so tried but I am fail. I am new in jsf and primefaces

SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
            at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:269)
            at com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.getProviderFromEntry(InjectionProviderFactory.java:317)
            at com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.findProviderClass(InjectionProviderFactory.java:285)
            at com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance(InjectionProviderFactory.java:116)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:335)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.InjectionException
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
            ... 18 more
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
        SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
        java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
            at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:269)
            at com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.getProviderFromEntry(InjectionProviderFactory.java:317)
            at com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.findProviderClass(InjectionProviderFactory.java:285)
            at com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance(InjectionProviderFactory.java:116)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:335)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
            ... 10 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.InjectionException
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
            ... 18 more
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
        SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
        SEVERE: Context [/TestJSF] startup failed due to previous errors
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
        SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
        SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1010)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:342)
            at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:141)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:328)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5146)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5810)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
            at org.apache.catalinaa.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-6060"]
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
        Aug 18, 2016 2:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
        INFO: Server startup in 8611 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Glassfish is an application server that supports JAVA EE while tomcat don't support this, a solution of apache org is apache TomEE.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to deploy a JSF application on Tomcat. JSF comes with JavaEE so you could try Payara Server or for something very simple try Payara Micro for deploying your application. Payara is derived from the GlassFish open source project.